# OpenOffice automation translate basic code to Delphi

Tags: delphi, automation, openoffice-calc

Hello please help to translate the next line of basic code to Delphi for the OOoTools.pas interface.

```
oChart.Diagram.SymbolType = com.sun.star.chart.ChartSymbolType.SYMBOL1
```

I know that the SYMBOL1 part is an enumeration and I think I have to use the MakePropertyValue fumction but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the simpler: `oChart.Diagram.SymbolType := SYMBOL1;`
Just my first shot, btw.

Comment: Hello, Workshop Alex thanks for your time  the constant is not known in the unit but is documented in http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/chart/ChartSymbolType.html and in http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/chart/ChartSymbolType.html#NONE so it is 1

Comment: @addelichtman: what do you mean by does not work, what error do you get?

Comment: Hello The_Fox I do not get an error, just the symboltype in the graph does not change, thanks Addelichtman

Comment: @addelichtman: Does the chart support SymbolType SYMBOL1? When I look at for example LineDiagram it says it only supports NONE and AUTO.

Comment: Thank you very much this line indeed turns off the symbols in scattered XY mode:   oChart.Diagram.SymbolType := -3;